# Why is result.status undefined in an extrinsic's SubmittableResult?

Tags: polkadot-js, substrate-contracts-node, extrinsicstatus

I am using the [substrate contracts node](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-contracts-node/) and my transactions are successfully submitted to the chain. I've checked using a dry run query and also checked in the explorer for the block after performing the tx. However, when I try to use the transaction result in polkadot-js, I cannot access fields such as `status`, as they are `undefined`.

I'm calling the `signAndSend` function of the extrinsic but the `result: SubmittableResult` I get is simply the extrinsic hash as a `Uint8Array`.

```
extrinsic
  .signAndSend(
    signerAddress,
    {
      ...options
    },
    (result: SubmittableResult) => {
      if (result.status.isInBlock) { //status is undefined here??
```

According to the `SubmittableResult` type in polkadot-js, `status` should be there:

```
export declare class SubmittableResult implements ISubmittableResult {
    readonly dispatchError?: DispatchError;
    readonly dispatchInfo?: DispatchInfo;
    readonly internalError?: Error;
    readonly events: EventRecord[];
    readonly status: ExtrinsicStatus;
```

Answer (score 2):

This was because I was instantiating the contract with `HttpProvider` instead of `WsProvider`. Changing to `WsProvider` allows the extrinsic result to be a subscription and therefore update with extra information when available.

I had also missed the following helpful message in the console logs:

> API/INIT: Api will be available in a limited mode since the provider
> does not support subscriptions